# Ternary Lazy Load - Order Dependent?

Tags: apex

I used to think ternary expressions could not be used in tandem with the `Lazy Load` pattern. Some time ago, I tried:

```
public String someProperty
{
    get
    {
        return (someProperty != null) ? someProperty : someProperty = 'assigned';
    }
    private set;
}
```

However, I got an error:

> Expression cannot be assigned

Then, [@cropredy](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2602) tipped me off that it is possible to user ternary expressions if you reverse the order, as the following will compile:

```
public String someProperty
{
    get
    {
        return (someProperty == null) ? someProperty = 'assigned' : someProperty;
    }
    private set;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, there is an implicit grouping that occurs with my original pattern:

```
return ((someProperty != null) ? someProperty : someProperty) = 'assigned';
```

However, you can still use the desired ordering by explicitly grouping the property assignment:

```
public String someProperty
{
    get { return (someProperty != null) ? someProperty : (someProperty = 'assigned'); }
    private set;
}
```

Success!

I find the use of ternary logic in lazy loading much more palatable when the order can be reversed. It is typically quite easy to one-line the truthy value, while the falsy value tends to overrun what is feasible to fit on one line. In this way, the pattern can often be compressed to just two lines, making it in fact less verbose than the traditional form:

```
public String someProperty
{
    get
    {
        if (someProperty == null)
            someProperty = 'assigned';
        return someProperty;
    }
    private set;
}
```

Not sure how useful this finding is, but it took me a long time to discover, so I thought it worth sharing.

Comment: Seems to me this is more about operator precedence rather than lazy loading pattern. Interestingly, in this document: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_precedence.htm It doesn't specify where ternary operator stands

Comment: Right, that's what tripped me up, but the quest itself was to execute ternary assignment in this order.